# How can I access more advanced information about packages and package dependencies?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

"I have been working as a Flutter developer for some time, but unfortunately I do not have a background in native development. I create various packages to reduce code repetition and build a foundation for an application, but my access to information about packages is unfortunately limited.

For example, I have two packages, A (the most basic package) and B, which contain util classes which are returns string values based on the application language. Naturally, the application language must be initialized before using these packages.

Package B requires Package A for its various components and may require the util that contains translations from Package A.

My question is, if my main application needs Package A and b, to ensure everything works correctly:

1.Should I initialize Packages A and B separately from the main application (with Package B also initializing Package A internally)?

or

2.If I initialize only Package B from the main application, can I use the translation util directly from Package A in my application since Package A is already initialized in package B?

In summary, can you recommend any resources, videos, or tutorials in Dart for managing packages and package dependencies, for questions like this and similar ones?

Comment: This is a bit unclear you said you aren't familiar with native development so in your case are packages A and B native packages or flutter packages ?

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap for flutter packages, I just want to learn a flutter package lifecyle, state managements etc. Are they working  as seperated apps or they are used on same source and in my case if I just initialize package A in Package B, is A package initialized for My main apps too or not?

Comment: Yes from what you’re saying if A and B are flutter packages then you can add package A as a dependency in the pubspec.yaml of package B . That way when you use package B in your app, package A will always be included .